# How to take xpath if the element sometimes have an extra class name?

Tags: html, xpath

my element is :

```
<div class="class1 class2">
```

but in some cases, there is an extra class like this:

```
<div class="class1 class2 fixClassCustom">
```

how can I handle that in xpath

i used to do this:

```
.//div[@class="class1 class2"]
```

but how can i handle both situations ?

Comment: `//div[contains(@class, 'class1') and contains(@class, 'class2')]` is this what you want?

Comment: That would also match `<div class="notclass1 notclass2">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) and [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/concat):

```
.//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' class1 ') and 
       contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' class2 ')]
```

Note that *`concat()` helps to avoid false positives* - for instance, the expression would not match `<div class="class10 class20">` case while the `//div[contains(@class, 'class1') and contains(@class, 'class2')]` expression that does not use `concat()` would match the element.

Comment: what's the reason behind concatenating? edit -> Nevermind, nice edit

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida sure, updated with a sample. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe it is not working, this is the website http://propertyonline.ae/property/listing/category/list_all/Residential/Rent/10?listing_category=Residential&listing_sub_category=Rent&page_size=10&order_by=&sort_by=&display_type=list&listing_type=&bedroom=&sq_ft=&price=&price= and this is the xpath `.//div[@class='properties-rows']/div[@class='row']/div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' property ') and contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' span9 ')]` it gives empty

Comment: @alecxe put it is not empty in the website, as you can see here http://i.stack.imgur.com/aZam3.png

Comment: @AniaDavid interesting..trying it in the Chrome Console: `$x(".//div[@class='properties-rows']/div[@class='row']/div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' property ') and contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' span9 ')]")` and getting multiple results - both with the `featured` class and without..